# Recursion version for this flattening?

Tags: javascript, recursion

Suppose a structure like this:

```
[
{name: 'a', children: [{name: 'c', children: [...]}]}, 
{name: 'b', children: [{name: 'd', children: [...]}]}
]
```

that goes say N levels deep.

What would a recursive way to get all the elements in a flat array be?

```
[{name: a}, {name: b}, ...]
```

Note that a parent could have multiple children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this;

```
function recursivelyAdd(el, array) {
    array.push(el);

    for (var i=0; i< el.children.length; i++) {
        recursivelyAdd(el.children[i], array);
    }

    delete el.children;
}
```

... note that it modifies the existing objects, by deleting the "children" property once processed. Remove the `delete el.children` line if you don't want that...

Use it like so;

```
var ar = [];

recursivelyAdd(rootPerson, ar);

// ar will now be all the people!
```

Comment: Thank you! I was hesitant of calling the function multiple times in one pass and thought the proper way was to have an extra parameter in the function passing some array that would represent state.

Comment: @rollingBalls: When using recusion, you need 1) a terminator (a way for the recursion to end) and 2) a way to collect your results (either by storing what's returned from each function, or passing a  "state" as you mention). In my recursive function, 1. is achieved when there are no children (since we won't recurse any more). 2 is achieved by adding to the array we're passing around.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification Matt. So, an alternative version with a state is also a "acceptable" solution. I think your implementation is more straightforward though :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var struc = [
{name: 'a', children: [{name: 'c', children: []}]}, 
{name: 'b', children: [{name: 'd', children: []}]}
];

function getNames(children) {
  return children.reduce(function(names, child) {
    return names.concat(child.name, getNames(child.children));
  }, []);
};

getNames(struc);
// ["a", "c", "b", "d"]
```

This answer removes the loop and doesn't modify the original object.

Comment: ... well, you remove the loop syntactically. `reduce()` will still do it internally :).

Comment: Yes. It's less for the developer to have to think about.